# How to update cards data on click of button which is in fragment

Tags: java, android, button, adapter, android-recyclerview

I have fragment called Receipt,in which i have spinner which loads customers below is the enter amount field and then button ADJUST and below is the recycle view displaying bills.
I need to update the cards data on clicking adjust button.
How to handle it ?? can somebdy help out. How to trigger cards

Here is ma code for Receipt Fragment

code for button adjust
 // adjust bills

```
  btnAdjust.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(!editTxtAmount.getText().toString().equals(0)){

                OrderApplication.ENTERED_BILL_AMOUNT = Integer.parseInt(editTxtAmount.getText().toString());
                Log.e("ENTERED_AMOUNT ",OrderApplication.ENTERED_BILL_AMOUNT + "");
            }
        }
    });
```

and here is my adapter for bills

```
  @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

        final Reciept items = aBillArr.get(i);

        viewHolder.textDate.setText(items.getrecptDate());
        viewHolder.txtVBillNo.setText(items.getBillNo() + "");
        viewHolder.textVamount.setText(items.getOrdAmnt() + "");
        viewHolder.textVpendingAmnt.setText(items.getPendingAmnt());

        int enteredAmnt,paidAmount = 0;
        String billNo;

        enteredAmnt = OrderApplication.ENTERED_BILL_AMOUNT;

        Log.e("Prachi","Entered Amount" +enteredAmnt);

        if(enteredAmnt != 0){

            for(int j = 0 ; j < aBillArr.size() ; j ++){

                int pendingAmount = Integer.parseInt(aBillArr.get(j).getPendingAmnt());
              //  billNo = Integer.parseInt(items.getbillNo());

                billNo = aBillArr.get(j).getBillNo();

                if(enteredAmnt > pendingAmount){

                    enteredAmnt = enteredAmnt - pendingAmount ;
                    paidAmount = paidAmount + pendingAmount ;
                    pendingAmount = 0 ;
                    db.updateReceipt(billNo,pendingAmount,paidAmount);

                    viewHolder.textVpendingAmnt.setText(items.getPendingAmnt());

                    Log.e("Prachi","Bill No" +billNo);
                    Log.e("Prachi","Pending Amount" +pendingAmount);
                    Log.e("Prachi","Paid Amount" +paidAmount);

                }
                else if(enteredAmnt < pendingAmount){

                    enteredAmnt = enteredAmnt - pendingAmount ;
                    paidAmount = paidAmount + pendingAmount ;
                    pendingAmount = abs(pendingAmount - enteredAmnt) ;
                    db.updateReceipt(billNo,pendingAmount,paidAmount);

                    viewHolder.textVpendingAmnt.setText(items.getPendingAmnt());

                }
                else if( enteredAmnt == pendingAmount){

                    enteredAmnt = enteredAmnt - pendingAmount ;
                    paidAmount = paidAmount + pendingAmount ;
                    pendingAmount = 0;
                    db.updateReceipt(billNo,pendingAmount,paidAmount);

                    viewHolder.textVpendingAmnt.setText(items.getPendingAmnt());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```